# including a resource instead of its location

Tags: c#, wpf, image

```
<Application.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="MyImageSource" UriSource="C:\Users\nwrobinson\Pictures\skyskanlogo.jpg" />
</Application.Resources>
```

hello,
im having an issue with the way C# handles resources, i understand that the above code is a reference to a picture, but i assumed that when the program compiled, it would include the picture for when it runs on other computers. instead, it just crashes when the resource is not present in that location. this makes no sense to me, there has to be a way to include the picture in the program so it will run right?

the way it was explained to me, the application always has to have a photo to reference, so does that mean every time i give someone the application i have to send them the photo as well, or is there a way to have the photo wrapped into the application.

this is my first WPF so im not 100% sure what going on all the time, it might have just been something that was overlooked.

thanks for the help

Comment: i also probably should have added that im building this application on .net 3.5 so it is vista compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the properties for the image in Visual Studio, you can select a Build Action. This can be one of many options, including copying the image to the build folder, embedding it as a resource, and others.

Depending on how you include the image in your project, you will need to use the **Pack URI** syntax to specify where the image can be found. It is not straightforward, but there are enough examples here ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) for when the resources are embedded etc. that you should be able figure it out. It typically involves specifying the assembly in which the resource is located and a relative path, with a very specific assortment of punctuation interspersed.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to add the picture to your project and set its **Build Action** to `Resource`. Then you can change your **UriSource** to something like

```
UriSource="pack://application:,,,/YourProjectAssembly;component/DirectoryName/FolderName/ImageName"
```